# Unknown class "viewControllerName" in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Basically I am getting the stated in error in my title 
"Unknown class coordinoteView in Interface Builder file." 
This however does not crash the program, but when I attempt to drag any label or outlet to the coordinoteView controller and run the program, it will crash giving me a sigabrt error. 
I have checked the following

1. The class name does match the name of the view
2. I have opened the xml source of the storyboard and deleted the "unknown class name" as stated in other solutions
3. The target membership is connected
4. I have completely re made the view class and the view on the storyboard.
5. I have read through many of the answers on here and cannot seem to find a fix to this error.

Comment: Try to delete DerivedData folder + restart Xcode. Sometimes Xcode do not replace old xib files correctly. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue - might be the problem, although I'm not seeing *"Unknown class coordinoteView ..."* message...

In your storyboard, you have a `Posted By : Anonymous` scene, that is set to `coordinoteView` class. The top-level `UIView` in that scene is ***also*** set to `coordinoteView` class.

`coordinoteView` is a `UIViewController` class, so you almost certainly don't want it to be the class of the `UIView`

Comment: Thanks, fixed it!